# SSRS Interactive Sorting by Value within multiple groups - how?

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

This should be easy but I can't seem to figure it out. All I want to do is be able to sort ascending/descending by Value across 4 groups. Here is my design...

[image]

This is the report (note that all the child groups are toggled by their parents)...

[image]

Toggling the sort widget doesn't do anything. I tried sorting by group but that just sorts the group values by alpha. Would appreciate some help with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should check the radio button for Groups, then select your Product group and use sum(fields!ThisTotalValue.value) for the sort by expression.

Comment: The expression in the sort by field, sum(fields!MergedTotalValue.value) does not appear to match the expression you are displaying in the field you want to sort, sum(fields!ThisTotalValue.value)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was holding me back. I based my sort expression on this expression: =Sum(Fields!MergedTotalValue.Value, "tbl_AUM_Summary")
rather than this one: [Sum(MergedTotalValue)]

Not sure why the former didn't work, though.